# How to make this DLL header file more reusable

Tags: c++, dll

I have a DLL written in Visual C++ that I am exporting functions from a header file.  I'm wrapping all the functions I want to export in one more function with a different name, to obfuscate the names and make life difficult for people trying to use its functionality without a license.  Currently, the format looks something like this:

```
#ifdef EXPORTS
   #define API extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
   #define API extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

CustomObject *MeaningfulFunction1(PCWSTR param);
API CustomObject *ObfuscatedName1(PCWSTR param)
{
    return MeaningfulFunction1(param);
}

void MeaningfulFunction2(CustomObject *param1, int param2, int &param3, int &param4);
API void ObfuscatedName2(CustomObject *param1, int param2, int &param3, int &param4)
{
    MeaningfulFunction2(param1, param2, param3, param4);
}
//repeat this style many times
```

Now this works just fine for exporting.  All of the code calling this DLL up until now has been written in C#, so I didn't need the header for importing... until now.

This header doesn't work for importing, even though I have the `extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)` definition, since `ObfuscatedName1` through `ObfuscatedNameN` have a definition, and there is no exported definition for `MeaningfulFunction1` through `MeangingfulFunctionN`.

I know I can modify it to look something like this:

```
#ifdef EXPORTS
CustomObject *MeaningfulFunction1(PCWSTR param);
#endif
API CustomObject *ObfuscatedName1(PCWSTR param)
#ifdef EXPORTS
{
    return MeaningfulFunction1(param);
}
#else
;
#endif
```

But that is tedious to write for a few dozen functions, and overall an eyesore.  **Is there an easier way to make this scheme work?**  Preferably with modifying the preprocessor definitions.  <s>I considered something like</s>

```
#ifdef EXPORTS
    #define OUT //
#else
    #define OUT
#endif
OUT CustomObject* MeaningfulFunction1(PCWSTR param);
```

This makes the first part easy, but I couldn't find as simple of a scheme for the second part.  Turns out the comments are stripped before the preprocessor sees it, so this doesn't even work.

I know I could reorder it to have all the normal names in one block, and the obfuscated names in a second, but I'd rather keep them adjacent to make it easier to tell which is which when I make modifications.  Thanks!

Comment: This just seems like a terrible idea.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious the obfuscation is a requirement by my company. I just need to find the least painful way to support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work out something that was reasonably painless given the requirements.

```
#ifdef EXPORTS
   #define REDIR
   #define API extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
   #define CleanName
#else
   #define REDIR / ## /
   #define API extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)
   #define CleanName / ## /
#endif

CleanName CustomObject* Function(PCWSTR param);
API CustomObject* Obfuscated(PCWSTR param)
REDIR {
REDIR    return Function(param);
REDIR }
;

 //...
```

This way, when exporting, `REDIR` does nothing, but on import, it becomes a comment (Visual C++ compiler concats `/ ## /` into `//`, so it is ignored.  Same goes for `CleanName`.  I also learned that having a `;` after a function definition is not an error, so I can just leave it dangling on the end. When the function body is included on exporting, the `;` does nothing, but when the function body is ignored on importing, the `;` becomes the end of the forward declaration of the obfuscated function name.

I tried hard to declare the defines like so:

```
#define Open / ## *
#define Close * ## /
```

However, that seems to insert an EOF in the middle of the file so the compiler can't process it.  If anyone figures out how to get that to work, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

`grep API your_header.h > import_header.h`

Then remove the

```
#define API extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
```

line which grep will pick-up from the top of the import_header.h and append a ; to the end of each function declaration. Then use that for imports.

Another thing you might try is make a header file that simply maps meaningful names to obfuscated names thusly:

```
#define MeaningfulName1 ObfuscatedName1
```

Then you can #include it everywhere, and only ever directly use the meaningful names in your code.

Overall, though, I think the whole scheme is a bad idea.